# Can't pip install Tensorflow 'msvcp140_1.dll' missing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying to `pip install tensorflow`, which works but after I install it, and then import it into my python module via `import tensorflow as tf` I get following error message:

```
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that
these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment
variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable
for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: 
https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

I installed the `msvcp140_1.dll` and put it into `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37` which is contained in my path environment variable.

As you can see I am using Python 3.7 as 3.8 is not supported by tensorflow.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4923

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find msvcp140.dll in your %windows%/System32 folder, once you installed VC++ DIST for VS 2015, for msvcp140_1.dll you need to goto this page

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

and in the section :Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019, pick the correct package with the arch of your PC.

Answer (score 9):

Just click this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads Then install

> x64: vc_redist.x64.exe

and restart your pc.

Comment: I just installed the x64 version, restarted my PC, and the problem persist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you this setup tutorial, it works on my computer. And you need python 3.6 for Tensorflow instead of 3.7.

https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/manual_setup.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Downloading Visual C++ from the url below works.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads