# I am getting Import Error in python 3.8.3

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was getting this Error while importing Tensorflow 2.0 in python 3.8.3

ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140.dll or msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: try updating your Windows or manually download these dll's

Comment: @deceze help me in this. I read tensorflow isn't supported in python 3.7 and 3.8 , but the official tensorflow page says it supports above 3.5-3.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777013/tensorflow-importerror-could-not-find-msvcp140-dll/50777261

Comment: Did you click that link and install the redistribuable?

Comment: I downloaded the two files vc_redist.x86.exe and vc_redist.x64.exe , what's the difference between both....? @ThomasSchillaci

Comment: The first one is for 32bit systems, the second one for 64bit

Comment: okay got it , installed it , now what....? @ThomasSchillaci

Comment: Are you still getting the error?

Comment: yess @ThomasSchillaci

Comment: I mean, all of the infos are in the error log: the next step is to check if your %PATH% environment variable contains an entry to those DLLs

Comment: sorry @ThomasSchillaci i don't know how to check that, can you help me with that please....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't pip install Tensorflow 'msvcp140\_1.dll' missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157335/cant-pip-install-tensorflow-msvcp140-1-dll-missing)

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci yeah but that worked in python 3.7 , I uninstalled the python 3.8.3 and installed 3.7